# Need help in identifying this action figure

Tags: object-identification

I was going through my old toys when i came across this - [image]

I remember getting this around 2016-2017 from London,  can somebody please help me in identifying this character?

I am pretty sure we can rule out Ben 10.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This appears to be a "Mattel Max Steel Claw Blast Dredd" action figure:

[image: Black Dredd figure with claw arm]

as seen in [this Amazon listing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00G989LZ2).

To unpack that, this is a Mattel action figure from the Max Steel line-up based on the [2013 TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Steel_(2013_TV_series)).  The character is [Miles Dredd](https://max-steel-reboot.fandom.com/wiki/Miles_Dread), in the ["Claw Blast" Dredd](https://max-steel-reboot.fandom.com/wiki/Claw_Blast_Dredd) form with the right arm in the shape of a blaster that fires a projectile.  According to the linked (fan) wiki page, the figure was released in 2014.

The figure is supposed to come with a small crab-like accessory figure called an "Ultralink."

[image: Claw Blast Dredd in original packaging]